# Android variables swap values in AsyncTask

Tags: android, variables, android-asynctask, swap

I have a program that shows the status of a server(whether is online or offline). I put in a spinner to show the users that its loading and in the AsyncTask i turn off the online/offline image and turn on the spinner while its loading and do the opposite when its done. The code does its job but i feel like its done by some glitch and could potentially break it later on down the line so id like to fix it now. Basically what happens is the variable for the online/offline image and the variable for the spinner swap values some how and im not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
public View background;
public View status;
public View loading;

class CheckStatusTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> { 

    //show loading
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);<-- this shows the spinner but should show online/offline
        //loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);<-- this shows the online/offline but should show the spinner
    }

    //check if server is online
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return CheckStatus.check();
    }

    //set status bar to offline if flag is false
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean flag) {
        status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);<-- this shows the spinner but should show online/offline
        //loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);<-- this shows the online/offline but should show the spinner
        if(!flag){
            background.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.offline);
            status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offline);<-- correct 
        }
    }

}

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        background = findViewById(R.id.status);
        status = findViewById(R.id.image); 
        loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        new CheckStatusTask().execute();
    }
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">

    <!--  Status  Starts-->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/online"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip">
            <!-- Online/Offline Start-->


            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <!-- Online/Offline Ends -->

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--  Status Ends -->


    <!-- Main Form -->
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:layout_below="@id/status">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#372c24"
            android:text="Home"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Main Form Ends -->
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As you can see the status variable is defined to show the online/offline image and the loading variables is defined to show the spinner but it does the exact opposite. This only occurs for this specific function everywhere else its currect.

Comment: in this line `android:background="@layout/online"` What does `@layout/online` pointing to? And what are you trying to achieve by setting a layout resource as the background of a LinearLayout?

Comment: online points to an image and the drawable offline points to a different image. that works fine, i had that in there before adding the spinner. the only issues im having is with the status and loading variables when setting them visible and invisible as they are swapped somehow

Comment: if it is an image it seems like it should be `@drawable/online` not `@layout/online` with layout it is going to take `online.xml` file from your layouts folder. Also, try commenting out the AsyncTask.start() for now and add this `status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` right after your findViewById() calls. report back if that properly hides the status or if it is messed up there too.

Comment: by AsyncTask.start() do you mean the new CheckStatusTask().execute(); and also i was thinking incorrectly and @layout/online points to an xml file that sets the background color of it which is changed from green to red depending on the status

Comment: yeah, comment that out, and try setting the visibility of status in onCreate() to see if it works correctly

Comment: alright thats weird it does not hide status it hides loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:background="@layout/online"
```

With this line you are setting the background of your linear layout to a shape drawable that is in your `res/layout/` folder.

drawable resources, such as shape drawables should be placed inside of `res/drawable/` folder. By storing that inside of your layout folder it is confusing the R.id values for your resources. I don't know exactly why the problem manifested itself in the way that it did. But moving those online.xml and offline.xml into `res/drawable/` and deleting the ones inside of `res/layout/` should fix it.

After you move the file change the line above to:

```
android:background="@drawable/online"
```

See [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) for more info about xml drawable resources.

Comment: I restarted the emulator and it fixed itself